# Use foreign keys not just for restraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to create a dynamic query that will know what table I am joining based on the foreign key. Is there a way to utilize a foreign key for that? I would like to create a statement that can look up where the foreign key points and use that to select the correct values. Something that would work like this:

```
"SELECT t.*, f.Name FROM $table t INNER JOIN {foreign table(will change based on the table selected and the foreign key it has)} f WHERE t.key = '$key'";
```

Comment: Have you not tried this?

Comment: @jeto Yeah I wasn't sure I added the tag because thats what I would use to make the query dynamic. Should I remove it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard What do you mean?

Comment: @Jeto I don't know how you would do it so I can't give more examples. Does that explain it any better?

Comment: Hmm, you can query the dictionary to see where an FK constraints points to and then build you second query using this information. But the question is, what would you need that for? You usually know what you want to query. Is this more of an academic question or can you elaborate what you want actually to do here?

Comment: @stickybit What do you mean by the dictionary? I have a single function that I use for multiple tables. I want to be able to look up a value using that same function. However, the lookup table changes based on the table selected.

Comment: The data dictionary or catalog where the DB stores the metadata (like what tables are there, what columns do they have, what data types have they or which constraints are in place, etc.) in or where from one can retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key information can be queried from the [`information_schema.key_column_usage` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html). Remember that:

- A foreign key may have several columns.
- A table may have more than one foreign keys pointing to the same table.

It's kind of tricky to do that in plain SQL. You'd need to write a stored routine and generate [dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). It's also likely to kill performance. If you have (at it seems) PHP at your disposal the dynamic SQL generation probably becomes easier and you're also able to implement some caching mechanism so `information_schema` is not queried every time.